# How do I change the text color for a part of an equation after a pause in beamer?

Tags: color

I want this in the same frame, not a different frame. Here is an example of what I'd like:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{color,xcolor,ucs}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,setspace,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\frame{\frametitle{NPDE}
\begin{itemize}
    \pause
  \item item 1 here
    \pause
  \item item 2 here
    \pause
  \begin{equation*}
          \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= {\color{red}u(n,t)}u(n+1,t) -u(n,t)u(n-1,t)
  \end{equation*}
  %then I want this on the next click:
  \pause
    \begin{equation}
        \notag
        \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=u(n,t){\color{red}u(n+1,t)}-u(n,t)u(n-1,t)
  \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But if you want the second part "on the next click", it will be on a different slide; perhaps you meant "I want this in the same frame, not a different frame"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `\only` overlay specification:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{color,xcolor,ucs}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,setspace,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\frame{\frametitle{NPDE}
\begin{itemize}
    \pause
  \item item 1 here
    \pause
  \item item 2 here
    \pause
  \begin{equation*}
          \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \only<4>{\textcolor{red}{u(n,t)}u(n+1,t)}\only<5>{u(n,t)\textcolor{red}{u(n+1,t)}} -u(n,t)u(n-1,t)
  \end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

And here are the fourth and fifth slides showing the relevant equation:

[image]

Comment: YES!! thank you Gonzalo!! and yes I meant the same frame (I'm still new to latex, but thank you!)

Comment: Adapting Gonzalo's suggestion, you could also define a command before `\begin{document}`, such as:

     `\newcommand<>{\colorize}[4]{\only<#1>{#4}\only<#2>{\textcolor{#3}{#4}}}`

and use it as 
    `\colorize{4}{1-3,5-}{red}{u(n,t)}`

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but the following is a bit more straightforward than the other answer provide (IMO).

Just add an overlay specification to the `\textcolor` command:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{color,xcolor,ucs}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,setspace,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\frame{\frametitle{NPDE}
\begin{itemize}
  \item<2-> item 1 here
  \item<3-> item 2 here
  \begin{equation*}
          \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \textcolor<3>{red}{u(n,t)}\textcolor<4>{red}{u(n+1,t)} -u(n,t)u(n-1,t)
  \end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a better way to do any of such changes imho. Works with most if not all environments and commands.