# Revealing parts of an array in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm making a `beamer` presentation that involves a lot of arrays. I want to be able to put an array on one slide; then as I progress through the frame I want to be able to make some parts of the array bold/put them in boxes, etc; step by step.

Currently I have multiple arrays on one frame and am uncovering each on in turn. However this does not keep the image in the same place. Ideally I'd like to be able to superimpose (or overlay) the images so I can reveal some numbers in the array becoming bold, etc.

How do I go about this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And please tell precisely what you want to uncover, make bold etc.

Comment: Perhaps this answer to a related question might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64295/127845

Answer (score 1):

You can use a number of different overlay specification macros to alternative between what's displayed on a slide. Below I've used `\only<num>{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

% Original unaltered frame
\begin{frame}
  Original unaltered frame:
  \[
    \left[
      \begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
        a & b & c & d \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        e & f & g & h \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8
      \end{array}
    \right]
  \]
\end{frame}

% Updated frame with slide-variations
\begin{frame}
  Updated frame with slide-variations:
  \[
    \left[
      \begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
        a & b & c & d \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        e & f &
          \only<1>{\eqmakebox[var]{$g$}}
          \only<2>{\eqmakebox[var]{$\mathbf{g}$}}
          \only<3>{\smash{\eqmakebox[var]{\fbox{$g$}}}} & h \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8
      \end{array}
    \right]
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've also incorporated the use of [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) that sets its contents in a box of similar width based on a `\eqmakebox[<tag>]`. Since your content may differ in size (width and/or height) from one slide to the next (by adding `\fbox` or `\mathbf` or whatever), this might be useful.